# If an array is stored from higher region of memory to lower region, how'll the indexing formula look like?

Tags: data-structures

[image]

If an array is stored from lower region of memory to higher region, we've this indexing formula.

$$ Address (A[i]) = M+(i-L)*w$$

Where:

M = memory location where first element is to be stored.

L= Lower bound for index

i = index

w = word length

But for the case in question, we have:

$$L<i<U$$

$$A_i > A_{i+1}$$

Comment: Hint: Subtraction

Comment: according to the info, the array is stored higher to lower in physical space...how is the array stored in the virtual space?

Comment: @RinkeshP could you elaborate in an answer? It'd be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array grows from a higher address to lower address, you need to subtract the offset from base address
$$Address(A[i])=M-(i−L)∗w$$

Comment: Can you point me towards derivation to this(either case)?

Comment: there is hardly any derivation involved, just a matter of in which direction you are traversing. You can easily work it out on pen and paper.

Comment: Could you share your workout? I didn't get it. That's why.

Answer (score 0):

From the formula,

$$ \text{Address} (A[L]) = M+(L-L)*w=M$$ and $$ \text{Address}(A[U]) = M+(U-L)*w$$

If $\text{Address} (A[L])>\text{Address} (A[U])$, you conclude that $w<0$.